# get an array of all a products attributes in magento

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, magento-1.4

I cannot figure this out!

I am trying to get a list of a products attributes into an array on the list.phtml page. I have tried everything. I have seen a lot of solutions that use

```
$attributes = $product->getAttributes();
```

but I cannot get this to work, it just brings up a blank page. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have spent hours and hours on this so far...

I am using Magento version 1.4.2.0

UPDATE: Here is exactly what I am trying to do:

```
$neededAttributes = Mage::helper('mymodule')->getNeededAttributes();
$attributes = $product->getAttributes();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
   if(in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $neededAttributes)) { 
      $attributename = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
  echo $attributename;
   }
 }
```

this is in the file gallery.phtml in design/adminhtml/default/default/catalog/product/helper/

For some reason, I cannot get the getAttributeCode function to return anything.

Comment: have you tried get product collection first?

Comment: Have you used step-by-step debugging with a debugger like XDebug?

Comment: Are you asking of the values of the attributes for that specific product, or a list of all possible attribute codes?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm guessing you need a list of only visible values. I say "values" because attributes are not the actual values, they are descriptors. The following is the salient parts from `Mage_Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes`:

```
$attributes = $product->getAttributes();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront()) {
        $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
        // do something with $value here
    }
}
```

You don't really need to duplicate this though since you can alter/use the template `catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml` which is already declared on the product view page as `attributes` block.

Comment: this is great and works on the frontend, but I am trying to use this in the file gallery.phtml in design/adminhtml/default/default/catalog/product/helper/ - any ideas? It seems to not be able to get the product variable in the same way

Comment: I posted exactly what I am trying to do in my original post. Hope you can help!

Comment: Since you don't actually need a product's values does it work if you create a blank product with `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')`? This might not respect different attribute sets, I'm not sure how to find that out.

Answer (score 14):

According to your question, you should be using `Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')` instead:

```
$productAttrs = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection');

foreach ($productAttrs as $productAttr) { /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute $productAttr */
    var_dump($productAttr->getAttributeCode());
}
```

You don't always have attributes in the `_data` (`getData()`) storage and you don't always need to load a product to get its attributes.

Comment: Gist with friendly array for select. https://gist.github.com/jruzafa/8776453a13717ff7b5a1

Answer (score 7):

It's rather easy and gives you an array of available product attribute names

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('product_id');
$attributeNames = array_keys($product->getData());
print_r($attributeNames);
```

If you need a attribute object collection you can call

```
$product->getAttributes();
```

If you need a product collection and after that you can perform the previously mentioned ways on each collection member

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

Comment: Might also note on this that you need to set "Used in Product Listing" > Yes in the Attribute settings

Comment: I am getting this array  [0] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 12
            [entity_type_id] => 4
            [attribute_set_id] => 4
            [type_id] => simple
            [sku] => 20707
            [has_options] => 1
            [required_options] => 1
            [created_at] => 2016-01-06 21:15:31
            [updated_at] => 2016-10-03 00:49:21
        ) How can I get additional attributes like name , product image , description etc